# How to make a physical copy of database?

Tags: db2, toad, db2-luw

I am looking for a solution to make a copy of a DB2 databaseusing Toad.

I have tried the `db2move` command like this:

```
db2move sample COPY -sn BASESAT -co target_db schema_map "((BASESAT,BASESAT4))" -u SATURNE
```

`BASESAT` is my database and `BASESAT4` is the copy I want to create

I get this error:

[image]

When I tried on command mode. I got this

Comment: You can use db2move command.

Comment: `db2move` is an operating system command, not a CLP command. It needs to be run from the OS prompt.

Comment: this is Interactive input mode, you should use Command mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried your solutions and i almost get it. I get this error "failed to connect to target database". I will add a screenshot in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution thanks to your help.
Here are the steps if someone else has the same problem:
1-create the database in which to copy (in my case BASESAT2) 
2-use db2move in command mode like this: 
db2move dbname COPY -sn SCHEMA_OF_YOUR_DBname -co TARGET_DB dbname_copy USER user_name USING password

Here is a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you.

to create a sample database;

```
 user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "create db sampledb"
DB20000I  The CREATE DATABASE command completed successfully.

user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 connect to sampledb

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = SAMPLEDB
```

sample table;

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "CREATE TABLE SAMPLETABLE  (COL1   CHAR(6)      NOT NULL,   COL2 VARCHAR(24)  NOT NULL)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

insert an dummy row;

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>db2 "insert into SAMPLETABLE VALUES ('test1','test2')"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
```

this is export;

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>mkdir data   
user@host:/home/db2inst1:>cd data/
user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2move sampledb export

Application code page not determined, using ANSI codepage 819

*****  DB2MOVE  *****

Action:  EXPORT

Start time:  Mon Jul 18 17:49:49 2016


Connecting to database SAMPLEDB ... successful!  Server : DB2 Common Server V10.5.7

EXPORT:    147 rows from table "SYSTOOLS"."HMON_ATM_INFO"
EXPORT:      0 rows from table "SYSTOOLS"."HMON_COLLECTION"
EXPORT:      5 rows from table "SYSTOOLS"."POLICY"
EXPORT:      1 rows from table "DB2INST1"."SAMPLETABLE"

Disconnecting from database ... successful!

End time:  Mon Jul 18 17:49:49 2016
```

to generate ddls.

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2look -d sampledb -e -a -o db2look.sql
-- Generate statistics for all creators 
-- Creating DDL for table(s)
-- Output is sent to file: db2look.sql
-- Binding package automatically ... 
-- Bind is successful
-- Binding package automatically ... 
-- Bind is successful



user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2 terminate
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```

this is second database.

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2 "create db copydb"
DB20000I  The CREATE DATABASE command completed successfully.


user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2 "connect to copydb"

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = COPYDB
```

change database name in db2look as below

```
CONNECT TO COPYDB;


user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2 -tvf db2look.sql 
CONNECT TO COPYDB

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = COPYDB


CREATE SCHEMA "DB2INST1"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

CREATE TABLE "DB2INST1"."SAMPLETABLE"  ( "COL1" CHAR(6 OCTETS) NOT NULL , "COL2" VARCHAR(24 OCTETS) NOT NULL ) IN "USERSPACE1" ORGANIZE BY ROW
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

COMMIT WORK
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

CONNECT RESET
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

TERMINATE
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```

You can also use import instead of load.

```
user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2move copydb load

Application code page not determined, using ANSI codepage 819

*****  DB2MOVE  *****

Action:  LOAD

Start time:  Mon Jul 18 17:57:41 2016


Connecting to database COPYDB ... successful!  Server : DB2 Common Server V10.5.7

Binding package automatically ... /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bnd/db2common.bnd ... successful!

Binding package automatically ... /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bnd/db2move.bnd ... successful!

* LOAD:  table "SYSTOOLS"."HMON_ATM_INFO"      
***  ERROR -3304.  Check message file tab1.msg!
***  SQLCODE:  -3304  -  SQLSTATE:       
***  SQL3304N  The table does not exist.

* LOAD:  table "SYSTOOLS"."HMON_COLLECTION"    
***  ERROR -3304.  Check message file tab2.msg!
***  SQLCODE:  -3304  -  SQLSTATE:       
***  SQL3304N  The table does not exist.

* LOAD:  table "SYSTOOLS"."POLICY"             
***  ERROR -3304.  Check message file tab3.msg!
***  SQLCODE:  -3304  -  SQLSTATE:       
***  SQL3304N  The table does not exist.

* LOAD:  table "DB2INST1"."SAMPLETABLE"        
  -Rows read:          1
  -Loaded:             1
  -Rejected:           0
  -Deleted:            0
  -Committed:          1

**Error occured -1

Disconnecting from database ... successful!

End time:  Mon Jul 18 17:57:43 2016






user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2 "connect to copydb"

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2
 SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
 Local database alias   = COPYDB

user@host:/home/db2inst1/data:>db2 "select * from SAMPLETABLE"

COL1   COL2                    
------ ------------------------
test1  test2                   

  1 record(s) selected.
```